# Finding the most secure way to change IAM user passwords with AWSPowerShell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-iam, identity-management, aws-powershell

I'm working on a script for a Windows tool that uses PowerShell to discover accounts and rotate passwords for various providers; I'm working on AWS IAM users now.

Once a PowerShell script is complete, you load it into the tool and the tool provides a web interface and executes the PowerShell script as NetworkService in PowerShell Core 7+.

In the script, I need to securely authenticate to a user's AWS infrastructure and then using a role (I assume?), list all IAM users and change passwords.

I need to do this in the more secure way possible as this script may potentially be controlling IAM user passwords for many different companies.

After a lot of research, I've come up with a really rough plan but I'm no AWS expert here and looking for advice.

When setting this up for the first time, the tool docs would:

1. Instruct the user to setup an IAM user with permission to update all other IAM user passwords? Is there a least privilege way to do this?
2. Create an IAM role using this trust policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ListIAMUsers",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:GetUser"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ChangeIAMUserPasswords",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:UpdateLoginProfile"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Once the prereqs have been set up, what's the most secure way to leverage the role? Should the tool:

- create a credential profile on the fly with `Set-AWSCredential -RoleArn` and possibly using the `SessionToken` parameter to create temp credentials then run `Update-IAMLoginProfile` to change the IAM user requested?
- make the user save a credential profile on disk once while logged into the server as an interactive user and then have the tool (running as NetworkService), use Get-AWSCredential reference that credential to assume the role and then change the password?
- I saw that AWS recommends using AWS IAM Identity Center for this?

I never realized how many options you have to authenticate to AWS until now!